# How to hide/remove ToolTipText Property in UserControl VB6

Tags: vb6, activex

The title says all, "How to hide/remove ToolTipText Property in UserControl" in Visual Basic 6 ActiveX Component.

I wrote an ActiveX Control and the control doesn't have/need a ToolTipText property and I wish to remove that automatically created property from it, but I don't know how!

Is there any API or something to remove that ToolTipText Property from Property Window?

[image: Hide-Remove ToolTipText Property]

Comment: Sorry, doesn't say it all for me.  What are you really asking?

Comment: Can you clarify? You are writing a UserControl in a VB6 OCX? And you want developers that are using your UserControl not to see the ToolTipText property in the property window? Or for ToolTipText property not to be available in IntelliSense when they are coding? Or what?

Comment: @MarkJ, Yes, **not to see the ToolTipText property in the property window**, Thank you for your help! ;-)

Comment: @HansPassant, WOW, great help and support from you, but not close enough! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.ToolTipText` property is a property of the control extender in VB6, NOT of your user control and as such you don't have access to hide it.
VB6 does however remove it (and all other UI related properties) when you set the `.InvisibleAtRuntime` property to `True`.

Comment: Unless he wants a visible UserControl with no tooltip :-)) Probably clearing `Extender.Tooltip` in `ReadProperties` event would do it.

Comment: Yes, I have a visible UserControl, actually I wrote an ActiveX Button control (custom drawn) and I need to get ride of that ToolTipText Property shown in the control Property window!

Comment: I too suspect you are stuck with it, and that your best bet is just to clear it to "" whenever set.

Comment: @BobRiemersma, Yes, I know that, already working that way, but I rather hide that property somehow! :-(